# Stop compiz from animating chromium history drop-down box?

Tags: chrome, compiz

I don't know how to stop compiz from animating the drop-down list from chromium browser, it only appears if you type something, and disappears when focus is lost.

Any ideas on how to do it? I just don't want the default window animation to be applied on that.

**EDIT**

Doesn't seem to work:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to do it through `ccsm`. In the animations plugin, you can add specific rules for specific programs or classes of programs:[image]

Clicking on "New" will bring up this dialog:

[image]

If you click on the `+` sign to the right of "Window Match" you will (finally) get to this window:

[image]

If you now click on "Grab" and then click on the menu you are referring to, the "Value" field will be populated with the ID of that menu and you can then apply specific animation settings to it. You may have to apply them to chromium as a whole if the drop-down list is not clickable but this should help you get started at least.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work ... uploaded a screenshot

Comment: @warl0ck You might try disabling effects for all drop down menus using something like this in the "Window Match" field: `(type=Menu | PopupMenu | DropdownMenu | Dialog)`